# Android Multiple List View in one activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I'm trying to put multiple list views in one activity.

Ive managed to get one to work correctly but am unsure how to get the second and third list views to show up on the same screen below each other.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="\nDay 1:"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/textView45"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="\nDay 2:"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:id="@+id/textView46"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Code:

```
public class workoutlist extends Activity {
    ListView listView, listView2, listView3 ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.workoutlist);

        // Get ListView object from xml
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[] { "Option 1",
                "Option 2",
                "Option 3",
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        // ListView Item Click Listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {


                // Show Alert
                if(position == 0) {
                    //code specific to first list item
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Coming Soon." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }

                if(position == 1) {
                    //code specific to 2nd list item
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Coming Soon." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

                if(position == 2) {
                    //code specific to 2nd list item
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Coming Soon." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

            }

        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Android documentation, you're not supposed to work with multiple `ListView` that way, because it doesn't work calculating its own height like other views, but instead it takes the available space.

What you could do is use tabs, that way you can show the 3 `ListView` in the same `Activity`, but in different tabs. Here is a [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html) on how to do that.

Basically you create 3 `Fragments`, 1 for each `ListView`, and then you use a `FragmentPageAdapter` subclass to return the correct `Fragment`.

Comment: Are you sure its not possible? I think ive seen other people use it. Am not sure how to do it this way bit complicated for me bit of a beginner.

Comment: Trying to do this not going well :( Could you provide me a template of this?

Comment: Lemme see if I can find one

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height of the ListViews to 0dp and use "android:layout_weight="1" in each of the ListViews.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>
```

If you meant under in the "z" axis than  you can change the LinearLayout to FrameLayout, set the height to "match_parent" in all of the listViews and just set Visibility to Gone on the lists you don't want to be shown.

Comment: Doesnt really answer my question haha

Comment: What do you mean? if you will do as I showed the lists will be one under the other...